# Given the following HTML and CSS how can I get the input elment to fill the width of its parent?

Tags: css, html, width

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="first">Some text in the first div</div>
    <div id="second"><input type="text" value="Some text in the input" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#first{
    width:100px;
    background:red;
    float:left;
}
#second{
     background:blue;
}
#container{
    overflow:hidden;
}
#container:after{
    clear:both;
    content:"";
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6GBts/2/

Comment: `input { width: 100% }`? divs automatically try to take up the maximum width available anyways.

Comment: Or displaying the `input` as a block-level element? `display: block;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want this

```
#second{
     background:blue;
     overflow:hidden
}

input{
  width:100%
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7v4de/)

Comment: OK thanks. And why does this work and simply adding {width: 100%} to the input element does not?

Comment: @Ben I have put the `overflow:hidden` in the parent of `input`, so that whatever part of input is exceeding from `#second` div boundary should get hide. If you simply put `width:100%` then it will not hide and come to next line.

Comment: understood - but can you explain why HTML/CSS works like this? What is the inclusion of `overflow:hidden` triggering to change the rendering in this way. `overflow:hidden` in other contexts merely clips.

Comment: yes you are right `overflow:hidden` is clip the extra content and so it is doing here as well. Are you confusing with `hide` and `clip`?

Comment: In this instance instead of clipping the content, the input field gracefully finishes at the end of the visible width of the parent div. Pure clipping would keep the width and behavior as if `overflow:hidden` were ommitted, with any overflow purely clipped off.